# php regex to alow slash in string

Tags: php, regex

Here is my regex to exclude special character other then allowing few like (-,%,:,@). I want to allow `/` also but getting issue

```
 return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%:@&-]/s', '', $string);
```

this works fine for listed special character, but

```
 return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%\\:&-]/s', '', $string);
```

does not filter `l` chracter to.

Here is the link to test:

http://ideone.com/WxR0ka

where it does not allow `\\` in url. I want to dispaly URL as usual

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a mistake in entering `http://` by `http:\\` also your regex needs to include `/` in exclusion list. This should work:

```
function clean($string) {
   // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
   // Removes special chars.
   return preg_replace('~[^\w %\[\].()%\\:@&/-]~', '', $string);
}

$d =  clean("this was http://nice readlly n'ice 'test for@me to") ;
echo $d; // this-was-http://nice-readlly-nice-test-for@me-to
```

#### [Working Demo](http://ideone.com/zGU1oY)